# Exception throwed when calling RegisterAsync of ProvisioningDeviceClient

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

I have a below method , written using `C#`

```
 public async Task<DeviceRegistrationResult> RegisterDevice(ProvisioningDeviceClient provClient)
    {
        DeviceRegistrationResult registrationResult = null;
        try
        {
            registrationResult = await provClient.RegisterAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (registrationResult.Status != ProvisioningRegistrationStatusType.Assigned) {
               

            }
           
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }
        return registrationResult;
    }
```

This method was called like this

```
   var deviceRegistrationResult = await _dpsDeviceClient.RegisterDevice(provClient);
```

I am getting below error

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.DeviceRegistrationResult> Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.ProvisioningDeviceClient.RegisterAsync()'.'

I am using version 1.5.2 of Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client library.

I have also tried with upgrading Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client to 1.19.2, this time it was not showing exception but my app is crashing. Strangely exception is not getting caught in `Catch` section.

The below code was used to create `ProvisioningDeviceClient`

```
 using (var transport = new ProvisioningTransportHandlerMqtt(TransportFallbackType.WebSocketOnly))
   {
   provClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.Create(GlobalDeviceEndpoint, "MyIdScope",
                     security, transport);
   }
```

Note: MyIdScope is have not mentioned in post for security purpose.

**.csproj file content**

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
 <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
 <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client" Version="1.19.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\ConnectivityLibrary\ConnectivityLibrary.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<None Update="appsettings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I also see the below exception in `provClient` object.

> '((Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.DefaultWebProxySettings)provClient._transport.Proxy).Credentials' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: Can you please share the .csproj file?

Comment: updated  .csproj file content

Comment: I tried sample [code](https://i.imgur.com/zH61vWl.png) with  ProvisioningDeviceClient with RegisterAsync in [3.1](https://i.imgur.com/rKLqOah.png)  [ouput](https://i.imgur.com/inSfHT7.png)

Comment: Could you please upload the code to github?

Answer (score 1):

Exception throwed when calling RegisterAsync of ProvisioningDeviceClient

Able use RegisterAsync of ProvisioningDeviceClient

I followed the below steps

- Register the [Azure IoT Hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaFIU.png)
- Registered the individual enrollment in [Azure DSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMnUW.png).

[image]

[image]

- Replace the [DeviceEndpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEqJu.png), [idScope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K96P7.png) ,[registrationId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJO9b.png) , [primaryKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMMIo.png).

Sample snippet code:

```c
            string globalDeviceEndpoint = "global.azure-devices-provisioning.net";
            string idScope = "Youridscrope";
            string registrationId = "YourregistrationId";
            string primaryKey = "yourprimaryKey";
            var security = new SecurityProviderSymmetricKey(registrationId, primaryKey, null);
            var transport = new ProvisioningTransportHandlerMqtt(TransportFallbackType.WebSocketOnly);
            var provisioningClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.Create(globalDeviceEndpoint, idScope, security, transport);
            RegisterDevice(provisioningClient).Wait();
        }

        static async Task RegisterDevice(ProvisioningDeviceClient provisioningClient)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registering with the device provisioning service...");
           var result = await provisioningClient.RegisterAsync();
          if (result.Status == ProvisioningRegistrationStatusType.Assigned)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Device {result.DeviceId} registered to {result.AssignedHub}.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Registration status: {result.Status}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]